# Bootstrap-datepicker background-color issue with active dates

Tags: css, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using [Bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) and I would like active dates to be round. I'm currently using `border-radius: 50%` on the td with the active date, but it's causing issues as I would like the date table to be zebra striped

```
table > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

table > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}
```

See [jsFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/zcvq0yhh/141/).

As you can see, obviously the background behind the round dates are visible.

Any idea how to get around this? Maybe either by letting dates be wrapped in a span inside each `td` or by using some css fix?

Comment: can you add Extra html code in switch case javascript ??

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything in the docs about it - so I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

See Basically you are change **border & background-color** in `td` then white background-color display . This Scenario all table are generated .see below simple example

**See small Example**

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.active
{
   background-color: green;
   border-radius: 50%;
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr bgcolor="#c2c2c2">
    <th class="active">Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> Then My opinion Best Solutions is you can set `Table`
>   **background-color**  and your required change  tr color.then you can not fetch this problem .

**Fiddle Demo** [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/co4v559s/1/)

Comment: It's still not quite there - checkout September 12th from your demo. It still has another background color visible behind the active date.

Comment: i know about it. in demo not remove your old and event style . i have remove old and  event style click http://jsfiddle.net/co4v559s/2/